# React element mapping equivalent on CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs, codeigniter

So let say I have this html element:

```
<div>
  <p>{name}</p>
  <p>{number}</p>
</div>
```

And also this array of object:

```
var obj = 
[
  {
    "name": "Luke",
    "number": "101",
  },
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "number": "102",
  }
]
```

I want to map the array value and put it on html element. In react I usually do it like this:

```
<div>
  {obj.map((value)=>{
      return(){
        <>
          <p>{value.name}</p>
          <p>{value.number}</p>
          </br>
        </>
      }
    }
 )}
</div>
```

The result will be:

> Luke101
>
> Mike102

Now I want to do it on CodeIgniter but I couldn't find the equivalent way. Maybe someone can help me to solve this or give reference. Thanks!

Comment: I believe the array_map function would work:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php foreach($obj as $name => $number){ ?>
   <p><?php echo $name ?></p>
   <p><?php echo $number ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```